# Lumix DMC FX10 - purple pictures in camera mode, normal and clear in video mode

Tags: troubleshooting

I found an old camera that I had from around 10 years ago. The camera takes all of it's pictures in purple. However, the video camera mode functions normally. I've cleaned the lense and tried all the different settings. What could be causing this? Many thanks

Comment: Is it possible to do a "factory reset" on the camera - it's possible there's a setting you're missing? If not, look carefully for any colour balance settings - the green/purple axis is complementary to the usual blue/yellow colour temperature axis.

Comment: Thank you, Philip. I'll see if I can find a way to do a factory reset and I'll check out the colour balance settings again. Many thanks,

Comment: A sample image might help. What you mean by “purple pictures” might be different from what I imagine from reading your description.

Comment: Instead of there being a variety of colours, as per a normal photo, all the tones are purple. The image is still clear. I will upload a photo when I can find the correct cable.